Is VS Code Server protected from CSRF?
I inspected my browser's cookies while using the VS Code Server, and I couldn't find any anti-CSRF token present. The only token I saw was "code-server-session".
Does VS Code Server have anti-CSRF token by default ?
If not, is there a way to enable it?
Additionally, I created a file within the VS Code Server and expected it to send a POST request with the file content (possibly encrypted) along with an anti-CSRF token. However, no POST request was sent at all. Perhaps a more sophisticated mechanism is used, like an open pipe to the server or something similar.
Considering this behavior, is an anti-CSRF token necessary for VS Code in general?
